# jQuery .hover not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

```
<div class="front_hover">
  <img class="bg_img" src="image.jpg" width="320px" height="400px"/>
    <div class="front_roll" style="display:none;">
        <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
    </div>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".front_hover").hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(".front_roll", this).fadeIn(200);
    },
    function () {
        jQuery(".front_roll", this).fadeOut(200);
    });
});
</script>
```

I have a site which is using jQuery to display content when the user hovers on a block on the front page. It's been working fine up until now, and it's just stopped working in Chrome. All other browsers seem to still be working fine.

The live site is [globalgeneration.co.uk](http://www.globalgeneration.co.uk/)

Comment: Your page seems to be using *jQuery 1.10.2*. The `hover` pseudo-event was deprecated in *jQuery 1.9*. Did you upgrade jQuery recently?

Comment: The hover is working, the problem is in the CSS positioning. If i change the `#content.front_content #front_top .front_roll` rule to have `position: absolute`, and remove the `top` and `left` properties, then it works fine

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The CSS 'absolute' does fix it. Still a little confused though. I built [the180project.org.uk](http://www.the180project.org.uk/), which is using the same version of jQuery, and the same code and it works fine.

Comment: @Martin your CSS is good, apart from in Firefox. The hover element appears in the wrong place. Any idea about that? Thanks

Comment: Make sure that it's parent has `position: relative;` in this case `.front_hover { position: relative; }`

Comment: Thanks @Martin that's done it. Still don't understand why it suddenly broke though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer, from the comments on the original post:

The jQuery hover is actually working correctly (fading the element in and out).

The problem is in the CSS positioning. If you change the `#content.front_content #front_top .front_roll` rule to have `position: absolute`, and remove the `top` and `left` properties, then it works fine

Make sure that it's parent has `position: relative;` in this case `.front_hover { position: relative; }`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with something like `$(menu).hover(funin,funout)`, where menu is `<div><ul>...`, which does use `position:absolute`.

Looking at the `event.target` in the funout, it turns out that in FF it is the `ul`, while in Chrome it is the div (in both cases `this` is the `div`).

Don't know exactly why, but setting `$("ul", menu).hover(funin,funout)` fixes it: in both cases the `event.target` is now the same; looks like it has to do with how Chrome handles the mouseleave event target...

HTH, JM2CW.

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code and it works ....

But there is an alternative ,
This should work :

```
jQuery(".front_hover").live("hover",

function () {
//Do something
});
```

or this way :

```
    $("table tr").live({
    mouseenter: function () {

    },
    mouseleave: function () {

    }
});
```